# change the background image of one back menu item on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css

i am working on a menu and its a breadcrumb style menu and what i want to do is when i hover mouse on any menu item, with respective changes on hover i also want to change the background image of the closest menu item(the one before the menu item i am hovering mouse). is it possible?? if yes kindly send me the related links. i my self search alot but failed. if its possible through jquery or css kindly tell me and send me links

my reputation is less than 10 so i cant upload image.

Comment: yes it is..unless you post some of your code...your reputaion won't stop you for posting your codes or thing that you have done till now atleast the HTML

Comment: nice yes u are right but my code will not describe what i want to ask my question is very simple

Comment: look at this js fiddel http://jsfiddle.net/rGFzJ/ in this when click on menu item it change the backgroung of whole body but what i want to do is to cange background image of the closest menu item like when click on item three it should change the bacground of item two as well and when click on item 2 it should change the backgroung of item one

Comment: hmmm.. but see to help you we need to recreate everything here.. HTML,jquery,CSS ( + assuming what we are creating , is what you are looking for )...most of the people seeing your post will leave as soon as they see there is nothing(codes) here..

Comment: yes .. see the fiddle is what is needed... you should add that to your question... :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if this jQuery snippet helps you:

```
$('.menu li a').hover(
    function() { $(this).parent().prev().find('a').css('background-image', 'url(new-bg.png)') },
    function() { $(this).parent().prev().find('a').css('background-image', 'url(old-bg.png)') }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `eq()` to get the previous li and chnage th background color with `css()`

try this

```
  $("a").hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = $("li").index( $(this).parent() );

    if ( i === 1 ) {
       $('li').eq(i-1).css({"background-color":"red"}); 
       $('body').css('background', 'beige');
    } else if ( i === 2 ) {
       $('li').eq(i-1).css({"background-color":"blue"});
       $('body').css('background', 'honeydew');
    } else {
       $('li').eq(i-1).css({"background-color":"green"});
       $('body').css('background', 'pink');
    }
  },function(e){
      var i = $("li").index( $(this).parent() );
      $('li').eq(i-1).css({"background-color":"transparent"});
  });
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/rGFzJ/32/)